# Get macro command names for menu items in Word

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto

I'm developing an addon for MS Word 2010 using VSTO. The Word has a "Customize keyboard" dialog:

[image: MS Word 2010 Customize Keyboard dialog]

"Commands" list contains built-in macro commands each assigned to some menu or action. They can be executed from VSTO with `Application.Run()` method.

I need to obtain records in form "Menu item name" - "Macro command name" - "Keyboard Shortcut" for the currently installed instance of Word.

What I tried so far:

```
Application.CustomizationContext = Application.NormalTemplate;
foreach (CommandBar bar in Application.CommandBars)
{
    // Name of menu group
    Application.Selection.InsertAfter(bar.NameLocal + "\n");
    foreach (CommandBarControl control in bar.Controls)
    {
        // Human-readable name
        Application.Selection.InsertAfter("\nName:" + control.accName
                   // Broad description
                   + "\nDescription:" + control.DescriptionText
                   // Keyboard shortcut
                   + "\nShortcut:" + control.accKeyboardShortcut);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `CommandBarControl` doesn't contain macro command name field. I'm wondering how to gather this and glue all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's time now to answer another my question which has got too much attention.

There's a bunch of Excel tables for each version of Microsoft Office which contain ID, command name, default shortcuts and some other information. Here's for [2010 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627). Using the provided tables it's now easy to obtain all we need:

```
var id = // Obtain from downloaded bundle
var name = // Obtain from downloaded bundle
var control = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Id:id);
var description = control.DescriptionText;
var caption = control.Caption;
var shortcut = control.accKeyboardShortcut;
var parentControl = control.Parent;
```